# Seeking free world roads WMS

Tags: openstreetmap, wms, service-recommendations

I am looking for a free WMS layer with road map. It needs to support NAD27 so we can display some old data on top of it. Long time ago we used to work with google maps; but they suspended the service unfortunately. I tried OpenStreetMap; but I did not see support for NAD27 (if I'm wrong let me know).

Answer (score 1):

You can always reproject OSM to met your needs. If you don't want to host the service yourself then you can reproject in the client or via a cascading WMS such as GeoServer or MapProxy,